# Why Secure GRPC calls do not reach ingress gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, istio, grpc-java

I have installed istio 1.22.2 inside kubernetes (1.12.x) with sds enabled. I have been following [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/) and I am able to do ssl termination at the ingress gateway for normal services (on HTTP/1.1). And I could see it in the access logs of the gateway.

gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 31400
      name: tcp
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: "review-this-co" # must be the same as secret
    hosts:
- "xyz.example.com"
```

**However when GRPC is used over secure channel I could not see any access logs. (Grpc client fails).** I Was expecting similar behavior for grpc as well(ie ssl termination at the ingress gateway).

NOTE: same grpc client works(call reaches the ingress gateway, visible in the access logs) with plaintext if the gateway is configured like following

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 31400
      name: tcp
      protocol: GRPC
    hosts:
    - "xyz.example.com"
```

**Network loadbalancer has been used (pass through)**

Comment: Could you please share the source code of grpc java client, configurations settings used to initialize Istio, especially ones related to Ingress gateway and the rest of manifest files to run grpc server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the thing here is that:

- GRPC currently works over a `HTTP2` type transport
- The current ingress is not capable of `HTTP2`

So are you sure your client is using `HTTP1`? Because otherwise it might not work.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Istio ingress proxy(ie envoy) do have support for GRPC(HTTP2). moreover, grpc calls reach the destined services without TLS/SSL.

Answer (score -1):

Try it out grpc greeter with istio, it works for me.

```
# greeter.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: greeter
  labels:
    app: greeter
spec:
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 50051
  selector:
    app: greeter
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: greeter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: greeter
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: tobegit3hub/grpc-helloworld
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: greeter
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50051
```

```
# gateway.yaml

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: greeter-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - 'xyz.example.com'
```

```
# virtualservice.yaml

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: greeter
spec:
  hosts:
    - 'xyz.example.com'
  gateways:
    - greeter-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: greeter
            port:
              number: 50051
```

```sh
# grpc greeter client
docker run  -it tobegit3hub/grpc-helloworld /greeter_client.py xyz.example.com:80
```